# How to serialize a dynamic object to a JSON string in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am passing a JSON payload to an API Controller, and one of the fields is dynamic because the field needs to be passed again as a JSON string to another API.  The dotnet core 3.1 middle layer shouldn't be concerned with typing, as the payload will change.

This is the object that is passed into the API Controller:

```
    public class GitHubAction
    {
        [JsonProperty("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Enabled")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(BooleanParseStringConverter))]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Action")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ExpandoObjectConverter))]
        public dynamic Action { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is a picture of that `dynamic` object looks like in VSCode:

[image]

When I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.Action);` the string result isn't being properly converted, but instead serializes to ValueKind: `"{\"ValueKind\":1}"`.

What I want to get is the action object value as a JSON string, which should look like `"{"createRepository":{"onboarding":{"service":{"organization":"foo","repositoryName":"foo-2-service","description":"A test service."}}}}"`

Is there a simple solution for serializing a dynamic object?

Comment: Is this using `Newtonsoft.Json`, or `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: `ValueKind` is from System.Text.Json, but `JsonConvert` is from Newtonsoft. It's quite possible you can't mix the 2 here. Try using `JsonSerializer.Serialize` instead of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Comment: There is a property named `ValueKind` of `JsonElement`: [`JsonElement.ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=netcore-3.1).  So *probably* your `dynamic Action` is actually a `JsonElement`, can you confirm please?  A [mcve] showing the JSON and deserialization code would be ideal.

Comment: The payload coming into the controller is being serialized using `System.Text.Json` pretty sure.  I am not wiring up Newtonsoft in Startup, but I am doing some internal stuff using Newtonsoft else where in the code.  

And yes, it is a JsonElement.  The POCO object I have in the OP might be misleadning.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem and I fixed it this way

```
using System.Text.Json;

string serializedObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(x.Action); //Instead of use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.Action);
```

Instead of `Newtonsoft.Json` you have to use `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question as System.Text.Json doesn't currently handle dynamic properties.

Comment: This worked for me, and I am using dynamic properties

Answer (score 8):

Use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of default `System.Text.Json`

Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package from `NUGET` and
`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()` in `Startup.cs => ConfigureServices()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.ExpandoObjectConverter* to help you with this.

```
dynamic action = new ExpandoObject();
action.YourProperty = new ...;
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(action, converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jsonString=s.Action.ToString();
```

This will give you the json string

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Newtonsoft.Json then follow this instructions :

in using section use this :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

and for Deserializing use :

```
var desrializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
```